# Powershell script correction

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get McAfee "AVDatVersion" and AVDatDate" from registry and I am able to get the registry path for getting the output like below.
But the problem here is , AVDatVersion which comes in the output is Hexadecimal value I want only the Decimal value to be captured in the output.
Also I am able to collect AVDatDate, but I want the output only as date, no other values.

Can anyone help me to correct this, So that I will get the ouput of AVDatveriosn as Decimal value and also the AVDatdate as only the date.

### Example

AVDatVersion  8633
 AVDatDate 2017/08/24

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to get the version of mcAfee agent.

```
$version = [Version](Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\Agent").AgentVersion
```

When the value is still in hex try to convert it with powershell.(Google)

For the date try the same line as above and adapt it